# About gaps between prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Consider some even integer number $n$.

Let: $$C = \{c_i|i - n \mod i\}_{i=2..n}$$

For example for $n = 50$:

$c_2 = 2 - 50 \mod 2 = 2$

$c_3 = 3 - 50 \mod 3 = 1$

$c_4 = 4 - 50 \mod 4 = 2$

$c_5 = 5 - 50 \mod 5 = 5$

...

Let $C_{\text{odd}} = \{c \mid c \in C,\text{c is odd}\}$ and $C_{\text{even}} = \{c\mid c \in C,\text{c is even}\}$

**Question:** Is it true that number $p = n + x$ where:

- $x$ - minimal odd integer number that is not contained in the set $C_{odd}$
- $n+x < n^2$

is minimum prime number greater than $n$?

Numerical results shows that it is true up to $10^6$.

Comment: Defining $n$ mod $i$ as the least non-negative remainder when $n$ is divided by $i$ means $n+c_i$ is the least multiple of $i$ greater than $n$, so if $x$ **is** contained in $C$ then $n+x$ is not prime, but the converse is not true as you showed with $n=50$, $x=15$

Comment: Why do you separate $C$ into odd and even subsets?

Comment: I tried to give an estimate of the gap between 
consequitive primes as an estimate of cardinality of sets $C_{odd}$ or
a $C_{even}$. In proving this, I made the same mistake as you and I realized that it is too difficult for me.
I decided to ask a question, suddenly this is some kind of well-known problem, 
just in a different formulation.

Comment: You have written

$c_2 = 2 - 50 \pmod 2 = 2$ 
(or it can be $ = 0$)

$c_5 = 5 - 50 \pmod 5 = 5$  (or it can be $ = 0$)

If you follow the general rule for the remainder (less than the divisor), the resulting value of $C_{odd}$ and $C_{even}$ will change. I am just curious whether the result still holds or not?